# How to Write isRoot() method in java

Tags: java, methods, tree, binary-search-tree

I have created a binary search tree node class. I defined the attributes

- parent
- left
- right
- key
- value

I want to implement a binary search tree. How do I write the `isRoot()` method?

As far as I know,

```
 public boolean isRoot(){
      //return true if it's the root
      //return false if it's not
 }
```

`parent` has been defined in the constructor so no need to pass it as a parameter. Any ideas how to start? I know how to go down the tree, nor up. All help is appreciated :)

Comment: Something like `return parent == null;` ?

Comment: if parent is null that means the root does not exist, am I right?

Comment: I think what you said is true, got it.

Comment: If parent is null, you are the root.  Something has to exist to run `isRoot()` on in the first place, so there's at least one element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Root node is the topmost node in the tree, it has no parent. Hence you can check if the parent of a particular node is null to decide if its a Root node.

```
 public boolean isRoot()
 {
   return parent == null;
 }
```

Comment: Well, maybe yes, maybe not. Suppose we introduce a `dummyNode` singleton to avoid `null`s, then we would test for `parent == dummyNode`. Or, or, or ...